# resume download of utorrent files

Tags: download, utorrent

I was downloading a file using utorrent, I clicked 'pause' and then restarted my pc. When I started download, it started from the beginning. Can I pause and then resume so I don't need to start all over again?

Answer (score 1):

It will check the % of files downloaded when restarted and will resume where it stopped before restarting. You don't lose the files downloaded unless you deletes those files from the downloaded location. Just wait until it checks how much data it has downloaded. You can use force start option to resume.